# scrapy-playwright getting null values

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, playwright

I am trying to scrape this page https://www.sephora.com/shop/skincare, but I am getting this bug:

```
{'title': None}
2023-05-22 13:56:59 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.sephora.com/shop/skincare>
{'title': None}
2023-05-22 13:56:59 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.sephora.com/shop/skincare>
{'title': None}
2023-05-22 13:56:59 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.sephora.com/shop/skincare>
{'title': None}
2023-05-22 13:56:59 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.sephora.com/shop/skincare>
{'title': None}
```

this is the code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageMethod
class SephoraSkinCareSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "sephora_skin_care"
    
    custom_settings = {
        'FEEDS':{
            'sephoradata.json':{'format':'json', 'overwrite':True}
        }
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request('https://www.sephora.com/shop/skincare', 
        meta= dict(
            playwright = True,
            playwright_include_page = True,
            playwright_page_methods = [
                PageMethod('wait_for_selector', 'div#css-1322gsb')
            ]
        ))


    async def parse(self, response):

        for product in response.css('div.css-1qe8tjm'):
            
            yield {
            'title':product.css('div a span css-12z2u5.eanm77i0::text').get()
        }
```

I am using scrapeops for proxies integration. The selector css-1qe8tjm give me the 60 products but any inside selector works.

Comment: I attempted to modify the selectors, specifically product in response.css('a.css-klx76'), in order to scrape some names. However, I was only able to retrieve a few names, not all of them. Consequently, I decided to make another attempt using the selector response.css('div.css-1qe8tjm'), I obtained 60 products with no corresponding name values as the beginning.

Comment: I tried to scrape another page with this script its works., So, I believe it's something about Sephora Policies or blocking features to prevent Scraping.